# What is the possible causes of "java.lang.OutofMemoryError" in a executing thread?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have met a Out of Memory problem in my application.

In one of my threads execution, there is a sudden `java.lang.OutofMemoryError` and make that threads die.

I have already select the memory heap size for the application is 20M.
I have dumped out the memory usage for the whole application before and after this OOM on this thread occurs, it does not exceed 20M.

I don't know how to tackle this problem.

So what is the possible causes of that `java.lang.OutofMemoryError`? and is there any method to tackle if I don't know the exact reason?

This is what i got!
Before this memory usage of the application is 8M

after this memory usage of the application is also 8M.

Comment: There are many potential causes. As a first step, could you post the details of the error; say the cause.

Comment: OOM usually occurs when you try to allocate a block of memory that cannot fit into a contiguous region of the heap. So having your total memory usage < 20M doesn't mean you won't (or shouldn't) get an OOM exception. Can you post some code & the stack trace?

Comment: What version of Java are you running on? Newer versions allow you to capture more information. You can also try adding -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to your java command to produce a heap dump when the error occurs.

Comment: J2SE 1.4.2. It maybe a little bit older...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that you run out of memory.  This might however be one of several kinds so the exact message is important.

You can attach to your running program with jvisualvm (in the JDK) and investigate the object tree to see where the memory went.  Hopefully you can deduce why it is still used (can be as simple as a static field holding a copy of the structure) and how to get rid of it.

When you found that, then put in try-finally clauses so that the memory is always released even if an OOM is thrown.

Comment: I know that it is out of memory on that thread. But no idea how this could be happen while the whole application of the memory does not exceed 20M yet. Is that a thread have a limited memory size which is <20M?

Comment: You might have a memory usage spike.  Show the stacktrace.

Comment: unlucky, the stacktrace doesn't print for me.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely to be because you didn't give your application enough memory.

> I have already select the memory heap size for the application is 20M. I have dumped out the memory usage for the whole application before and after this OOM on this thread occurs, it does not exceed 20M.

The heap size will never be more than the maximum.  This is what having a maximum means. ;)

Comment: i did. because to tackle the OOM, i try to dump out the memory usage for a period of time interval. I found that before and after the java.lang.OutofMemoryError occurs, the memory usage are only 8M.

Comment: If you attempt to create an array like `new byte[length]` and the length is 12M or more, this would be expected behaviour.  I would look at the line of code where the OOME occurs.